# Pushing objects into an array is returning an empty array

Tags: arrays, ruby, queue, each, block

### Problem

I have a method called queue, belonging to the `Board` Class that returns an empty array. I am having trouble pushing modified objects to this array. Currently it returns an empty array.

```
def queue
  queue = []
end
```

### Functionality Explained

I have a `rules` method, that belongs to the `Board` Class that conditionally calls `queue_for_birth` or `queue_for_death`

```
def rules(cell)
    if something
      cell.queue_for_birth
    else something_else
      cell.queue_for_death
    end
  end
```

This method is being called multiple times in an each block contained in the `game_logic` method also belonging to the `Board` Class. 
Each time `rules` is called, and it `queues_for_birth` or `queues_for_death`, it should add that instance of cell to an array called queue

```
def game_logic(cells)
    cells.each_with_index do |cell,index|
      if index == 0
        rules(cell) #push to the queue
      end
      if index == 1
        rules(cell) #push to the queue
      end
    ...
```

Here is where the logic that adds cells to a queue lives, it belongs to the `Cell` Class, which inherits from `Board`

```
def queue_for_birth(queue)
  @will_survive = true
  queue << self
 end
```

However, whenever I call board.queue, an empty array is returned.
`=> []`

Comment: why doesn't your queue function return []? Why queue = []?

Comment: thats a good observation. no particular reason.

Comment: maybe you can check how to do a memoization with ruby.

Comment: _"I have a method [...] that returns an empty array. I am having trouble pushing modified objects to this array"_ – that's because your method creates a new array every time it is called. You probably want to return the same array instance instead.

Comment: _"[...] `Cell` Class, which inherits from `Board`"_ – that sounds odd. Is a cell actually a special kind of board? And does it make sense that a cell knows about queues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an instance variable `queue` to the board class solved this

```
class Board
  def initialize(live_cell_count, queue)
    @live_cell_count = live_cell_count
    @queue = queue
  end

  def queue
    @queue
  end
```

Inserting `queue.push(cell)` in the conditional successfully appends each cell to the `queue` array.

```
def rules(cell)
    if something
      cell.queue_for_birth
      @queue.push(cell)
    else something_else
      cell.queue_for_death
      @queue.push(cell)
    end
  end
```